# impossible to run a test through the selenium RC on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc

I run a test through selenium RC and it works fine. I use this command line:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "SeleniumProfile" -htmlsuite "*firefox" "https://www.google.com" "testSuite1.html" "result.html"

I try to run the same command on chrome by replacing "*firefox" by "*googlechrome" and it fails:

Chrome is open but displaying the following message : "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer"

I got the same result by removing -firefoxProfileTemplate "SeleniumProfile" in the command line.

Do you have any idea of what I have to modify to make it works?
Thanks by advance,
Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to point to Chrome driver, so add this:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\grid2\chromedriver.exe
```

Download the driver here: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
and modify the path wherever you want.

Of course, you have to remove the Firefox profile reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the answer, I will try this soon. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tried it - made no difference. Do I need to tell PHPUnit to do something different?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following two lines which should fix this error:-

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();